# Linear transformation with diagonalizable power

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Let $f: \mathbb{C}^5 \to \mathbb{C}^5 $ a linear transformation such that $f^3$ is diagonalizable, but $f^2$ is it not.

Is it true that $f$ necessarily has a $3 \times 3$ jordan block with a null diagonal?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen can you justify it?

Comment: If $A$ is a Jordan block of size $m\times m$ and eigenvalue $\lambda\neq0$ then the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $(x-\lambda)^m$. If $A^k$ is diagonalizable, its minimal polynomial must be $y-\lambda^k$. Therefore $A$ is a zero of $x^k-\lambda^k$ as well, but this is not divisible by $(x-\lambda)^2$. When $\lambda=0$ that changes...